# Nvidia drivers have no xorg.conf file

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg

I have recently bought a Cyborg RAT7 mouse and this mouse doesn't work properly under Ubuntu. I found a tutorial (link below) on how to fix this. The problem is though, that I don't have the xorg.conf file.

Is there a different file for Nvidia drivers? Or do I create one?

http://fcns.eu/2011/04/01/cyborg-rat-7-mouse-under-linux/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xorg.conf is deprecated, you can use /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ instead. Read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Logitech_Marblemouse_USB for example.

Comment: Thank you. However, I do not see any file specific to my RAT7 mouse?

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer create you own file like 50-mouse.conf, where 50 is priority, with section 'InputClass' inside.

Comment: That worked! (And now I know what the numbers stand for!) Thanks!